# Preserve DataGridViewRow.Tag property in databound DGV when sorting data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to keep the tags from being nulled as soon as I sort the grid?

If not, is the Tag property actually useful for anything except non-databound usage?

Comment: Which method/approach are you using to sort it?

Comment: dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you last question, you are setting the Tag of DataGridViewRow objects. And they might very well be re-created during a Sort operation. Use reflector to make sure, but I would start looking for a workaround.

In general, the Tag property is a last resort.

You could use a `Dictionary<object, object>` to couple your data to the `dgvr.DataBoundItem` as key.

Comment: I am, and it looks like you're right.  If is DataSource null DataGridView.Sort() calls an internal Sort method on the Rows object.  If DataSource has a value it calls the Sort method on the dataConnection member.  That disappears into a ratsnest of interfaces; but I assume it eventually ends up somewhere in DataTable and ends up recreating the rows.  Times like this make me nostolgic for MFC where I could trace into the framework at runtime and confirm if the rows were getting replaced by looking at pointer addresses...

Comment: The DataRows in the DataTable are certainly not recreated (they end up as the DataBoundItem in the dgvr). Try using them a little more.

Comment: To Clarify I was referring to the DataGridViewRows that have the Tag property that is getting wiped out.